# Arduino Power On notebook PC

Tags: arduino, power, keyboard, mobile

Is it possible to "Power On" notebook PC with Arduino (or with USB keyboard) without pressing notebooks power button ?
Notebook PC is Acer 5720Z.

Answer (score 4):

Your laptop may support "wake on keyboard", where pressing a button on an external USB keyboard can wake it up.

If that works, you may be able to use your [Arduino as a HID keyboard](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=99.0) and send the right key code.

Failing that, most PCs support Wake On LAN, where a specially crafted packet can wake the machine. http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/ArduinoWaker

Comment: I can then wake (wake on LAN) with Arduino, and I don't have to wake through LAN (this way is ok) ? And, I have to buy or build Arduino or Arduino-Ethernet ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need an Arduino with ethernet transceiver capable of sending raw ethernet frames. Anything with the ENC28J60 would be fine.

Comment: I have set up wake on LAN with software, thanks anyway